# Check if an app is pre-installed or protected on OS X

Tags: swift, macos

Checking the app by the author 'Apple' isn't a good choice because some other apps from Apple like 'Xcode' or 'Numbers' are not system apps.

I also thought about 'Date Added' but it seems not a good choice either.

[isDeletableFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1408087-isdeletablefile) fails as well.

Comment: I don't think so, same as the author. For example: Xcode ("com.apple.dt.Xcode")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information seems to be encoded in a folders extended file system attributes.

running xattr on Mail, Maps, Stocks and Messages shows the are marked with com.apple.rootless

```
xattr /Applications/Mail.app/
com.apple.rootless
xattr /Applications/Maps.app/
com.apple.rootless
xattr /Applications/Stocks.app/
com.apple.rootless
xattr /Applications/Messages.app/
com.apple.rootless
```

while other apple apps dont have this

```
xattr /Applications/Xcode.app/
-
xattr /Applications/Numbers.app/
-
```

--

The extended attributes API, declared in , has functions for getting, setting, listing, and removing attributes:

```
ssize_t getxattr(const char *path, const char *name, void *value, size_t size, u_int32_t position, int options);
int setxattr(const char *path, const char *name, void *value, size_t size, u_int32_t position, int options);
ssize_t listxattr(const char *path, char *namebuf, size_t size, int options);
int removexattr(const char *path, const char *name, int options);
```